# Copying cells to another sheet by offset method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy cell values to a sheet by using the offset method, It works fine but it is not pasting cell values adjacent to first copied cell values. (Want to copy After 3 rows)
My Code does this 
[image: My Code does this]
End Goal is this
[image: End Goal is this]

And code looks like this

```
Set destSht = Worksheets("Final")
 With ActiveSheet

 For Each C In .Range("A17", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

  If .Cells(C.Row, "A") = "Element: Linear" Then
  C.Offset(1, 7).Value = "Straight"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0) = C.Offset(1, 7).Value

  C.Offset(1, 8).Value = "=RC[-6]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 1) = C.Offset(1, 8).Value

  C.Offset(1, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 2) = C.Offset(1, 9).Value

  C.Offset(1, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 3) = C.Offset(1, 10).Value

  C.Offset(1, 11).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[2]C[-9]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 8) = C.Offset(1, 11).Value


  ElseIf .Cells(C.Row, "A") = "Element: Circular" Then
  C.Offset(3, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[3]C[-4]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, -3) = C.Offset(3, 6).Value

  C.Offset(3, 7).Value = "Arc"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0) = C.Offset(3, 7).Value

  C.Offset(3, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C[-6]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 1) = C.Offset(3, 8).Value

  C.Offset(3, 9).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C[-5]"
  destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 2) = C.Offset(3, 9).Value
```

Please Help with your suggestions

Comment: When you run the code, use f8 to step through the steps instead of just running it fully. Then you can see where your counting is off and fix it.

Comment: @a-burge Thanks, But the problem is that when "Else if" part  code copies values after "if" part code, it doesn't check that last row is empty or not.....In brief...I want to check if the whole row is empty or not before copying "if" or "if-else" code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer (Removed 3rd Header row and changed numbers in offset)

```
With Worksheets("Source")     
For Each C In .Range("A17", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
If .Cells(C.Row, "A") = "Element: Linear" Then
 destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Straight"
 C.Offset(1, 2).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count,7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)
 C.Offset(1, 3).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count,7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3)
 C.Offset(1, 4).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count,7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)
 C.Offset(3, 2).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count,7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8)
ElseIf .Cells(C.Row, "A") = "Element: Circular" Then
 destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Arc"
 C.Offset(1, 2).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count,7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)
 C.Offset(1, 3).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count,7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3)
 C.Offset(1, 4).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count,7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)
 C.Offset(14, 2).Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count,7).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8)
```